# Rounding discrepancy in .Net

Tags: .net, rounding

I've been investigating the answer to this question for a while but cannot find an answer, so I thought of asking it here.

.Net (C#) offers two ways of rounding double values, both with a call to Math.Round() but specifying a different MidPointRounding option, either ToEven or AwayFromZero. So far so good.

It turns out that the AwayFromZero method might not always perform as expected for certain values, such is the case when rounding 2.135 to 2 decimal places, where the result is 2.13 when the expected result would be 2.14. This "error" is well documented in the .Net documentation under the Note to callers section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx

Rounding the same value with the ToEven method also rounds it to 2.13.

However, when displaying the original value to screen (2.135) with the help of the `ToString("C")` method, which converts the value to string rounded to 2 decimal places, the displayed value is 2.14.

It turns out that rounding with `ToString("C")` rounds values correctly away from zero without the errors found in the Math.Round, the only problem is that the result is a string, and I do not want to have to parse the result again to have a number properly rounded.

Does anyone know which rounding method uses `ToString("C")` method internally?

Does anyone have any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Fire up [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and find out for yourself.

Comment: How about not using floating point for currency values?

Comment: The second question cannot be explained (most likely) here, because it would require someone at Microsoft to explain the reasoning (which for extremely minor behaviors are very rarely explained).

Comment: Unfortunately, not using floating point values is not an option at this stage of the project.

Comment: Enjoy your rounding errors then. Tbh that's like saying "Doing things correctly isn't an option at this stage. We must do it the wrong way.".

Comment: Note that just for the rounding, this is as easy as `Math.Round((decimal)2.135d, 2)`. It's still awful, but it gives you the "correct" rounding.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as far as your questions are concerned...

Yes, and it doesn't help you. it doesn't "really" round the number at all - it's working with the string representation of the number. Floats and doubles are *not* decimal numbers - they're binary numbers; they have a fixed precision in binary, not in decimal. Only when you convert it to a string (or, say, a `decimal`) will it really be decimal.

Yes, and it's right there on the MSDN page. The rounding operation involves multiplying the number with 10 to the power of `digits`. This causes precission loss in some case (related to the "double is not a decimal".

The proper way to deal with this is of course to use the right tool for the job. Doubles aren't decimal, so don't expect them to be. Any conversion of a double to a decimal (string or number, it doesn't matter) will mean a potential precision loss.

A workaround is to convert the double to decimal first, do the rounding, and then convert it to double again:

```
(double)Math.Round((decimal)2.135d, 2);
```

However, it is just that - a workaround, a cheat, a hack. It doesn't guarantee you anything, because you're still working with numbers that aren't decimal. Just like you can't represent `1 / 3` without loss of precision in a decimal number, you can't represent `1 / 10` in a binary number. The fact that it appears that you can use a `0.1D` is because every time you display the number as string, it is in fact rounded - this gives floats the appearance of "decimals", even though they're not. When it fails to give you what you expect, we call it a precision error, but it's not an error in floats themselves - it's just that if you expect things to behave a way they're not designed to behave like, you're doing it wrong.

That's just one of the reasons why you really should use `decimal` for money operations - it doesn't guarantee infinite precision, but what it does guarantee is that you'll get the same results as a human accountant (who also uses decimal numbers with finite precision in practice).

Comment: Hi Luaan, I totally agree with your statement, and in fact, I was fully aware of all those issues. What bothers me is why ToString("C") doest it always right. I guess that you pointed the reason why, the real value might not be storable in the double datatype.

Comment: Some more info, after decompiling ToString i see it calls an internal framework method named "extern string FormatDecimal(decimal value, string format, NumberFormatInfo info)", so a method that directly returns a string. I cannot decompile further as it is an extern method.

Comment: `(decimal)2.135d` doesn't really make sense, you'd use `2.135m`

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yeah, I know. But this is not supposed to be a constant - the OP has a double, and wants to round it properly. So I've shown how to do that by casting that double to a decimal.

Comment: "what it does guarantee is that you'll get the same results as a human accountant" so what way do accountants do it?  The way `Decimal.ToString("c")` does it, which is always "away from zero", or using banker's rounding, which would make more sense but isn't the case with `ToString` like I said?

Comment: @rory.ap Depends on the application - neither is better in general. Banker's rounding is usually used where you have to add large amounts of numbers together - where the rounding error tends to average out. Most people use away from zero when doing rounding - and it's definitely less surprising in a method like `Decimal.ToString()`. Really, people rarely use rounding when accounting for e.g. their life expenses - you usually have a price that's already rounded. The main problem is calculating things like taxes, where you can get ugly rounding issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to floating point math.  Floating point types simple do not have accuracy you think they do.  While you could complain that what you think is "2.135" is not rounded correctly--this may in fact be represented in memory as something more like 2.135000001--which should *correctly* be rounded to 2.14--which the docmentation you referenced alludes to.

I'm not going to repeat or reference the reams and reams of floating-point information with regard to C# or the many other languages, other than to say do your research.  Look at just Stackoverflow and see the numerous questions on this very topic.  It has be asked and answered.

Short answer: use the correct type for the work you want to do.